# aspx visible property

Tags: asp.net

I am doing below code, but i am still able to view that tr, it is not becoming invisible. I aslo tried using as property....Please help....

```
public bool ControlEnabled() {return false; }

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

 <asp:MultiView ID="mv" runat="server">
 <asp:View ID="view1" runat="server">
 <table class="homediv">
<tr id="RAggMkttr" runat="server" Visible='<%# ControlEnabled() %>' >
  ---
public bool Test { get { return true; } }

<tr id="RAggMkttr" runat="server" Visible='<%# Test %>' >
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`RAgMkttr.DataBind()` fixes the issue

Comment: I thought you didn't want to do this at all from code behind.... What's the point then?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's already a server-side control, you should be able to simply set the Visible property on code behind as so:

```
RAgMkttr.Visible= ControlEnabled();
```

**Update**

In order to make code blocks work inside your table, you need to remove the `runat="server"` property from your `tr` element and instead do this:

```
 <%if (GetControlEnabled())
 {%>
   <tr id="RAggMkttr" >
     ....
   </tr>
 <%} %>
```

Comment: I have many tr in the page to make them visible or not....so i dont want to write code in aspx.cs page...so i am trying to do in aspx page

Comment: Then try doing *<%=GetControlEnabled()%>* instead of *<%#GetControlEnabled()%>*

Comment: It is giving me error if i am using that way...'<tr id="RAggMkttr" runat="server"   Visible='<%= ControlEnabled() %>' >'Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= ControlEnabled() %>' for the 'Visible' property.

Comment: Then do *<%=bool.Parse(GetControlEnabled())%>*

Comment: @user1546173 I just provided an update to my answer. I am afraid that's the only way you will be able to make it work if you want to be able to call the `GetControlEnabled` method.